# Crear una cadena de conexión con SQL en Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

```
 public class Datos
    {
        public static List<Clientes> CargarClientes()
        {
            try
            {
                List<Clientes> listaClientes = new List<Clientes>();
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Estoy haciendo un proyecto por capas en asp.net c# y quiero crear la cadena de conexión, donde tengo capa de presentación, datos, entidades, negocio. Me encuentro en la capa de datos pero no se como llamar a la base de datos. Ya intenté con ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings pero no me deja.

Comment: Agrega más detalles, ¿qué error te da? ¿y si nos muestras las librerías que has importado?

Comment: Has agregado la referencia a `System.Configuration.dll` a tu proyecto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder usar el ConfigurationManager es importante exista una cadena de conexión  válida en el web.config, por ejemplo:

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="NombreDeTuCadena" connectionString="data source={tuservidor};initial catalog={tubasededatos};integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=NombreDeTuAplicacion" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Para usarla en el código, sería algo así:

```
public class Datos
    {
        public static List<Clientes> CargarClientes()
        {
            List<Clientes> listaClientes = new List<Clientes>();
            var clientes = new List<Clientes>();
            using (var connection = GetConnection())
            {
                using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TuCampo FROM TuTabla", connection))
                {
                    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                    connection.Open();
                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var ordinal = reader.GetOrdinal("TuCampo");
                        var result = reader.GetValue(ordinal);
                        clientes.Add(new Clientes()
                        {
                            TuCampo = (string)result
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            return clientes;
        }

        private static SqlConnection GetConnection()
        {
            return new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        }

        public static string ConnectionString
        {
            get
            {
                return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NombreDeTuCadena"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Te recomendaría implementar un ORM como Entity Framework Core (si usas .Net Core) o Entity Framework 6 (si usas .Net Framework), esto te ahorraría mucho trabajo de acceso a datos.